# How to use PHP/Curl to post a file to restful api?

Tags: php, curl, pipedrive-api

I'm trying to post avatar images from my website to pipedrive using PHP/Curl. The docs require a multipart/form-data encoding. I can't seem to get the actual file to post. I've tried several ways to send the file from various how-to's but every time pipedrive returns "no file attached". I've pasted my current attempt below, any ideas?  Or perhaps just point me to an example that would work?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $params['filesize']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
   array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data')
);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$params = array(
    'id' => $PDid,
    'file' => plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ )).'tmp/'.$filename,
    'filesize' => filesize(plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ )).'tmp/'.$filename)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set the `$params` variable at the top of your script before you use it. It does you no good at the bottom.
2. Read the documentation for [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) and follow the example there.

Specifically, you should set the relevant file options like this:

```
// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile('cats.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');

// Assign POST data
$params = array('test_file' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

In the code you posted, it looks like you are missing `CURLOPT_POST`. And Your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` isn't working because as I said `$params` has not been initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't passing the file correctly. When I incorporated the CURLFile() classed it worked just fine. The $params array was defined in another class and passed to my curl wrapper. I should've placed it above, sorry for the confusion.